Assigening colour to point based on value
I have a set of 2d points:
P = {{0,0}, {1,0}, {0,1}, {1,1}}

at each point I computed the 3d vector field:
F = {{0.346949,0.767122,0.539584}, {-0.533817,-0.525173,0.662747}, {-0.111271,-0.0195383,-0.993598}, {0.262737,-0.52081,-0.812235}}

From here I wish to plot the points in a 2d plot such that if the value of the z-component of the respective vector field is less then -0.9, it takes on a red colour. For all other points, I would like it to take on a black colour.
edit:
I have tried to adopt the solution from a previous post. In this case, the information for the colour of the point comes from a different array configuration then mine and im not sure how to adapt it.

What have you tried?

Possible duplicate of 307477. Define col = If[Last@# < -0.9 , Red, Black] & and then PointValuePlot[ P -> col /@ F].

I understand that you want to plot the 2D points and choose the colors according to the third component of the 3D points:
p = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
f = {{0.346949, 0.767122, 0.539584}, {-0.533817, -0.525173, 
    0.662747}, {-0.111271, -0.0195383, -0.993598}, {0.262737, \
-0.52081, -0.812235}};

Graphics[{PointSize[
   0.03], {If[f[[#, 3]] < -0.9, Black, Hue@1], Point[p[[#]]]} & /@ 
   Range[4]}, Axes -> True]


